# django cache conditional view processing latest_entry

Tags: django, caching

I have a model called aps

```
class aps(model.Model):
    u=models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='u')
    when=models.DateTimeField() #datetime when row was inserted
    a=models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='a')
    a_read=models.BooleanField()
    a_last_read=models.DateTimeField()
```

The records from aps are retrieved like this:

```
def displayAps(request, name)
    apz=aps.objects.order_by('-when').filter(u=User.objects.get(username=name))
    return render_to_response(template.html, {'apz':apz})
```

And further they are shown in template.html ...

What I am trying to achieve is actually what django docz mention [here about conditional view processing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/conditional-view-processing/)

I do something like:

```
def latest_entry(request, name):
    return aps.objects.filter().latest('when').when

@cache_page(60*15)    
@last_modified(latest_entry)
def displayAps(request, name)
    apz=aps.objects.order_by('-when').filter(u=User.objects.get(username=name))
    return render_to_response(template.html, {'apz':apz})
```

If new rows are added the content is not modified, but retrieved from cache. I need to delete the cache files and 'shift refresh' the browser to see the new rows.

Anyone sees what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: have a look at the response headers. Is there an `expire` header?

Answer (score 2):

If you take out the `cache_page` decorator, does it work?

The `cache_page` decorator is the first piece of code that actually gets called in your view function. It is checking the timestamp, and returning the cached data, as it is supposed to. If the cache hasn't expired, the `last_modified` decorator won't ever be called.

---

You probably want to be more careful about mixing conditional response processing and static caching, anyway. They accomplish similar things, but using very different mechanisms.

`cache_page` tells django to only use the view to render an actual response every *n* seconds. If another request comes in before that, the same rendered content will be returned to the client -- whether it is actually stale or not. This reduces your server load, but doesn't do anything to reduce your bandwidth.

`last_modified` handles the case where the *client* says "I have a version of this page that is this old; is it still good?" In that case, your server can check the database, and return a very short "It's still good" response if the database hasn't changed. This cuts down your bandwidth needs significantly for those cases, but you still need to go to the database to determine whether the client's cache is stale or not, so your server load may be almost the same.

Like I mentioned above, you can't just apply cache_page before last_modfied -- if the database has changed, cache_page won't know about it. Worse, if the cache timeout *has* expired, but the database hasn't changed, then you might end up caching the "304 Not modified" message, and sending *that* for all subsequent visitors for the next fifteen minutes.

You could apply the decorators in the other order, but you have to make a request from the database for each request, and you could still get into a situation where the database has changed, but the cache hasn't expired -- in that case, the client could still be getting the old version of the page, even though the server has already hit the database to determine that it has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

The filter depends on some logged user or something, you should id this user in cookies and use django's vary_on_cookie.